# complicated substring of URL string in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, substring, amazon-redshift

I have different strings of URL

```
/kampane/luxury-shoes/damska-obuv-v11574-negro-38-cerna
/pl-accesoriu-gopro-caps-doors-uni/
/crossbody-kabelka-clutch-eclipce-negro-51x50p7-2000.html
http://www.rozbaleno.cz/chladnick…/mraznicka-guzzanti-gz-40f
```

etc

I need to substring them for that part after the last slash, but, if after the last slash is empty space I need to take the part before it. Also i need to delete everything after the dot, if the dot is after the substring I need.
So my result of substring those strings above is:

```
damska-obuv-v11574-negro-38-cerna
pl-accesoriu-gopro-caps-doors-uni
crossbody-kabelka-clutch-eclipce-negro-51x50p7-2000
mraznicka-guzzanti-gz-40f
```

I am not able to write a code not to lose any data. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use regular expressions and substrings.  However, this might be sufficient:

```
select (case when url like '%/'
             then reverse(split_part(reverse(url), '/', 2))
             else reverse(split_part(reverse(url), '/', 1))
        end)
```

Comment: thank you but its not complete... I also need to delete everything after .html include the '.html' and also '?'

Comment: @LucieSperkova . . . That is not the question you asked.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with appropriate sample data.  I think that changing a question in a way that invalidates answers is impolite, because it attracts downvotes to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to be inpolite, I really appreciate your help, thank you! but i wrote that i have a also string /crossbody-kabelka-clutch-eclipce-negro-51x50p7-2000.html and i need to delete everything after dot. and thats not what this result is doing. But i probably found a solution:

case when right(pagepath,1) = '/' then regexp_replace(regexp_substr(left(pagepath, LEN(pagepath) -1),'[^*/]+$'),'.html(.*)|\?(.*)') else regexp_replace(regexp_substr(pagepath,'[^*/]+$'),'.html(.*)|\?(.*)') end